# The equivalent definition of tangent cone in normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, non-smooth-analysis

I am trying to prove that $v \in T_{S}(x)$ if and only if $\lim \inf_{t \downarrow 0}d_{S}(x+tv)/t=0$ and $d_S$ is the distance function of $S$ and S is a subset of the normed space $X$.

For the necessity, $v \in T_{S}(x)$, then by the definition of tangent cone, there is a sequence $v_i$ in X converging to $v$, and a positive sequence $t_i$ decreasing to $0$, such that $x+t_iv_i \in S \ \forall i$. Since $d_{S}(x+tv) \geq 0$, then we have $\lim \inf_{t \downarrow 0}d_{S}(x+tv)/t \geq 0$, on the other hand, $\lim \inf_{t \downarrow 0}d_{S}(x+tv)/t \leq \lim_{i \to \infty}d_{S}(x+t_{i}v_{i})/t_i=0$, deduce that $\lim \inf_{t \downarrow 0}d_{S}(x+tv)/t=0$. **I am not sure the proof is correct and fail to prove the opposite direction.** Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a missing step before your inequality $\liminf_{t\downarrow 0}d_S(x+tv)/t\leqslant \lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}d_S(x+t_iv_i)/t_i$ for the necessity. It is the fact that $d_S(x+t_iv)\leqslant d_S(x+t_iv_i)+t_i||v_i-v||$ thanks to $d_S$ being 1-lipschitzian.

For the opposite direction, there exists sequences $t_i>0$ decreasing to $0$ and $\varepsilon_i>0$ converging to $0$ such that $d_S(x+t_iv)<\varepsilon_i t_i$ hence there exists a sequence $x_i\in S$ such that $||x+t_iv-x_i||<2\varepsilon_i t_i$ $(*)$. Put $v_i=\frac{x_i-x}{t_i}$ : $x_i=x+t_i v_i$ so from $(*)$ we get $||v-v_i||<2\varepsilon_i$ and thus $v_i$ converges to $v$, $x+t_i v_i$ belongs to $S$ so $v\in T_S(x)$.

Comment: Is $d_{S}(x+t_iv)<\varepsilon$ obtained from the definition of $lim \inf$, I have some trouble in understading $\lim \inf$, can you give some reference about $\lim \inf$. When passing limit to $\|v-v_i\|<2\varepsilon_i$, then we get  $\lim \|v-v_i\|<0$, but we always have $\lim \|v-v_i\| \geq 0$, and it seems is a contradiction, how to duduce $v_i \to v$.

Comment: $\liminf_{t\rightarrow 0} f(t)$ is the smallest limit of  $f(t_i)$ for any sequence $(t_i)$ converging to $0$. When you pass to the limit, strict inequalities become not strict so as $0\leqslant ||v-v_i||<2\varepsilon_i$ the squeeze theorem   gives $\lim_{i\rightarrow \infty}||v-v_i||=0$

Comment: Once you have picked a sequence $(t_i)$ converging to $0$ such that $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}d_S(x+t_iv)/t_i=0$ you can for instance put $\varepsilon_i=d_S(x+t_iv)/t_i+1/i$ in my answer. Don't forget to tell if you find it useful.

Comment: If $\lim\inf_{t\to 0} f(t)$ is the smallest limit of $f(t_i)$ for any sequence $(t_i)$ converging to $0$, that is exists $t_i$ such that $\lim_{t_i \to 0} f(t_i)=0$. In this case, we can get $\lim_{i \to \infty} d_{S}(x+t_iv)/t_i=0$, then by the $\varepsilon-\delta$, for all $\varepsilon >0$, exists $\delta>0$ such that $d_{S}(x+t_iv)/t_i < \varepsilon$ when $|t_i|<\delta$, the value of $\varepsilon$ is fixed, why $\varepsilon_i$ converging to $0$